# Is there any danger to using the same tf2_ros buffer across different message queues?

Tags: ros, transform, ros-kinetic, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's the short of it. I have a ROS node with 4 different message queues that service callbacks for 4 separate classes. I'm wondering if I can safely provide the same tf2_ros::Buffer reference to all four of those classes, for use with transforming sensor_msgs and geometry_msgs messages between coordinate frames.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326483/is-there-any-danger-to-using-the-same-tf2_ros-buffer-across-different-message-queues?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2019-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can do that. The API is thread safe.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-06-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1